# Pathfinder Lance Damage Ruling

Tags: pathfinder-1e, mounted-combat

I am playing a cavalier with a lance.The lance description states "A lance deals double damage when used from the back of a charging mount. While mounted, you can wield a lance with one hand."

My GM says that to him the wording means that you only double the lances damage.
Example: a 2d6 lance does 4d6. But my Strength bonus and power attack bonus would not be doubled.

So in total the attack would be 2d6(base)+2d6(doubling)+ 8(strength and power attack)for a total 4d6+8 damage roll.

But if I'm reading the rules about multiplying damage correct it states that.

"Sometimes you multiply damage by some factor, such as on a critical hit. Roll the damage (with all modifiers) multiple times and total the results."

This seems to mean that 2d6(base)+2d6(doubling)+8(str and power attack)(doubled) for a total of 4d6+16. Much like that of a x2 critical.

If someone could clarify which reasoning is correct, and why then I would be grateful.

Comment: @MrLemon Correction: double everything you would double on a critical hit. Sneak Attack and other bonus damage dice are explicitly not multiplied on a critical hit or other damage multipliers.